# C++ member function definition class prefix shortcut (also template)

Tags: c++, class, templates, definition

Given the following class declaration:

```
template <int N>
class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
};
```

and the following definitions:

```
template <int N> 
MyClass<N>::MyClass() {
}

template <int N>
MyClass<N>::~MyClass() {
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Do I have to write `MyClass::` every time (with and without templates)?
2. Do I have to write `template <int N>` before every constructor and destructor?

Comment: Yes, yes. Anything else would run into ambiguities and such, wouldn't it?

Comment: Macros may be of some help here in alleviating the burden of such boilerplate.

Comment: @Lingxi God no. No no, no no no, no no. No. No.

Comment: By the way: I recommand reading [this FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates) about templates (and [other things](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/)).

Comment: @eclipse Hey, I was just about to write an answer to your C++ linking error question you asked a bit ago. If you didn't fix it yet, the short answer is that `inline` functions absolutely have to be defined in the header. So either you put it all completely in the header or you remove the `inline` and you can split it again. Hope it helps you.

Comment: You a real bro. I figured it out on my own. I just googled in the wrong direction. Gave you some upvotes ;-)

Comment: @eclipse no problem, glad I could help. And thanks for the upvotes they are appreciated but maybe a bit overdone. SO got protection against users abusing the system and upvoting lots of their own posts from a second account, etc... so they might be reversed since it seems that you upvoted a whole 10 of my answers. A single upvote would have been more than enough already =D. Just to let you know for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [class.mfct]:

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.

If you are defining your member functions outside of the class definition, you need to write `MyClass::` every time. Since `MyClass` is a template, you need to qualify that you're defining the `template <int N> MyClass<N>` member functions. The answer to both of your questions is yes (although for #2, it's for *every* member function - not just the constructor and destructor).